# Representation of python dictionaries with unicode in database queries

Tags: python, unicode, orientdb

I have a problem that I would like to know how to efficiently tackle.

I have data that is JSON-formatted (used with dumps / loads) and contains unicode.

This is part of a protocol implemented with JSON to send messages. So messages will be sent as strings and then loaded into python dictionaries. This means that the representation, as a python dictionary, afterwards will look something like:

{u"mykey": u"myVal"}

It is no problem in itself for the system to handle such structures, but the thing happens when I'm going to make a database query to store this structure.

I'm using pyOrient towards OrientDB. The command ends up something like:

```
"CREATE VERTEX TestVertex SET data = {u'mykey': u'myVal'}"
```

Which will end up in the data field getting the following values in OrientDB:

```
{'_NOT_PARSED_': '_NOT_PARSED_'}
```

I'm assuming this problem relates to other cases as well when you wish to make a query or somehow represent a data object containing unicode.

How could I efficiently get a representation of this data, of arbitrary depth, to be able to use it in a query?

To clarify even more, this is the string the db expects:

```
"CREATE VERTEX TestVertex SET data = {'mykey': 'myVal'}"
```

If I'm simply stating the wrong problem/question and should handle it some other way, I'm very much open to suggestions. But what I want to achieve is to have an efficient way to use **python2.7** to build a db-query towards orientdb (using pyorient) that specifies an arbitrary data structure. The data property being set is of the OrientDB type EMBEDDEDMAP.

Any help greatly appreciated.

**EDIT1:**

More explicitly stating that the first code block shows the object as a dict AFTER being dumped / loaded with json to avoid confusion.

Comment: `{u'mykey': u'myVal'}` is *NOT* JSON, it's a Python dictionary. The JSON equivalent would be `{"mykey": "myVal"}` which is very similar looking to the Python dictionary, and is valid in Python, but the original is not valid JSON.

Comment: @cpburnz I didn't actually state that it was JSON. I said the representation ended up like that (after using dumps / loads -> python dict).Though I don't really see that it really impacts the problem that is presented, I still want to thank you for pointing out that it apparently was unclear. Updated the question.

Unless your comment really, between the lines, was that I should use (import) json and utilize json.dumps on the dict for this, which I agree would be one way of doing it.

Comment: You said, that you have a command: `"CREATE VERTEX TestVertex SET data = {u'mykey': u'myVal'}"`, but you need `"CREATE VERTEX TestVertex SET data = {'mykey': 'myVal'}"`. You need to `json.dumps(your_python_dict)` to normal JSON.

Comment: @sobolevn Yeah, I guess so. The db-driver I write doesn't use json itself, it is meant to operate on any python structures you wish to store, compatible with the orientdb data types, but I guess I could import json just for the utility to use dumps on dicts and lists. Perhaps that is the way to go. I'll leave this up for a while to see if more people have valuable input or concerns/thoughts to the fundamentals of what I'm doing, otherwise I'll post that as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Is your goal to have an a special representation of maps/lists/strings, where strings are single quoted since OrientDB expects this format?

If this is the issue at hand, then a simple recursive function to render Python list, dict, and string into that format is probably the easiest approach, and the cost of the query creation should be dominated by the cost of query execution, so make things more efficient than this simple approach is probably not worth it.

Comment: @DanOblinger Actually I think json.dumps() works really well. It can be used on more or less all datatypes I've tested so far and return the right format that I could use in a query string. Going to test a bit more still. To answer your question, yes, that is more or less what I'm trying to achieve. It doesn't have to be single-quotations though, as long as quotation marks are kept around strings (which json.dumps return for strings of course). I agree on your reasoning regarding optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went on to use json.dumps() as sobolevn suggested in the comment. I didn't think of that one at first since I wasn't really using json in the driver. It turned out however that json.dumps() provided exactly the formats I needed on all the data types I use. Some examples:

```
>>> json.dumps('test')
'"test"'
>>> json.dumps(['test1', 'test2'])
'["test1", "test2"]'
>>> json.dumps([u'test1', u'test2'])
'["test1", "test2"]'
>>> json.dumps({u'key1': u'val1', u'key2': [u'val21', 'val22', 1]})
'{"key2": ["val21", "val22", 1], "key1": "val1"}'
```

If you need to take more control of the format, quotes or other things regarding this conversion, see the reply by Dan Oblinger.

Answer (score 0):

Dargolith:

ok based on your last response it seems you are simply looking for code that will dump python expression in a way that you can control how unicode and other data types print.  Here is a very simply function that provides this control.  There are ways to make this function more efficient (for example, by using a string buffer rather than doing all of the recursive string concatenation happening here).  Still this is a very simple function, and as it stands its execution is probably still dominated by your DB lookup.

As you can see in each of the 'if' statements, you have full control of how each data type prints.

```
def expr_to_str(thing):
    if hasattr(thing, 'keys'):
        pairs = ['%s:%s' % (expr_to_str(k),expr_to_str(v)) for k,v in thing.iteritems()]
        return '{%s}' % ', '.join(pairs)
    if hasattr(thing, '__setslice__'):
        parts = [expr_to_str(ele) for ele in thing]
        return '[%s]' % (', '.join(parts),)
    if isinstance(thing, basestring):
        return "'%s'" % (str(thing),)
    return str(thing)



print "dumped: %s" % expr_to_str({'one': 33, 'two': [u'unicode', 'just a str', 44.44, {'hash': 'here'}]})
```

outputs:

```
dumped: {'two':['unicode', 'just a str', 44.44, {'hash':'here'}], 'one':33}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I haven't tried it yet. Though, do you have any opinions on using json.dumps() compared to your self-made solution? I've tried json.dumps() for a while and it seems to provide the exact format I need in my queries, at least for the data types I've tested.

Comment: @dargolith: dumps will likely be faster, but you cannot control its format.  it will be valid JSON.  in particular valid JSON uses double quotes, but it looked to me like you wanted single quotes around your strings.  if you need that kind of control, then you can use a hand-crafted dumper as I have shown.  Cheers, --dan

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and sorry for being unclear about what was required or not regarding the quotes. Either works fine in my case, but your solution is great as reference as well when you need more control as you said.